# Uploading data in elastic search from file

Tags: java, python, json, logging, terminal

I want to insert data into elastic search.I have file containing 250 documents How do I insert data efficiently? https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JRZj8myVu1UHJ3jxZzzb8LSKKMicY0Qi this is one of the file

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do so, depending on the source file format. The Elasticsearch documentation is a really good starting point:

- [Elasticsearch 7.1 Getting Started Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-explore-data.html)
- [Elasticsearch 7.1 Bulk API Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Once you've read that (strongly recommend tou know the basics of the process), you can use the elasticsearch_loader tool:

[elasticsearch_loader Tool](https://github.com/moshe/elasticsearch_loader)

Comment: Can you give a example with file name in elasticsearch_loader?

Comment: `elasticsearch_loader --es-host https://your-es-server:port --http-auth user:password --index your-index --id-field your-id-field json your-file-name --lines`

Comment: it is showing error. "Invalid value for "files":  scheme is not supported"

Comment: what is id-field?

Comment: Should not there be any option between json and file name.

Comment: Seems you are using other file format than JSON. If so, change the command to the corresponding with your format (read the elasticsearch_loader help): 

`elasticsearch_loader --es-host https://your-es-server:port --http-auth user:password --index your-index --id-field your-id-field **json** your-file-name --lines`

In other hand, If you are trying to load a JSON file and ge that error, your JSON file could be malformed (again, check the elasticsearch_loader help).

The `--id-field` parameter holds the field inside your source file you want to use  as Elasticsearch document id.